# Generating solid spheres

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling

I'd like to generate random uniform samples from n-dimensional solid spheres.

My current method is this

```
def sample_sphere(d, npoints):
    points = np.zeros((npoints, d))
    for i in range(npoints):
        r = np.random.rand() #random radius
        v = np.random.uniform(low= -1, high=1, size=d) #random direction
        v = v / np.linalg.norm(v)
        points[i] = r * v
    return points
```

But unsurpringly, this method gives a higher concentration of points near 0, since the sampling density is not proportional to the volume:

[image]

How can I sample uniformly?

Comment: You need to fix the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic interpretations of a spherical distribution:

## 1. Bounded solid sphere

The probability of getting a point at a given radius is given by the volume of a shell with thickness `dr` at that radius: `p(r) ~ r^D` up to a constant. The radial CDF is therefore `(r / R)^(D+1)`, where `R` is the outer radius and `D` is the dimensionality. The sphere has to be bounded unless you want to select from all of space.

A standard way to generate samples given the CDF is to invert it:

```
random_radius = R * np.pow(np.random.uniform(0, 1), 1 / D)
```

By the way, a common way of picking properly uniform directions is to use the Gaussian distribution ([see here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)):

```
random_direction = np.random.normal(size=D)
random_direction /= np.linalg.norm(random_direction)
```

You can, and should, vectorize your function. There is no need for looping:

```
def sample_sphere(r, d, n):
    radii = r * np.pow(1 - np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(n, 1)), 1 / d)
    directions = np.random.normal(size=(n, d))
    directions *= radii / np.linalg.norm(directions, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return directions
```

Notice the `1 - np.random.uniform(...)`. This is because the range of the function is `[0, 1)`, while we want `(0, 1]`. The subtraction inverts the range without affecting the uniformity.

## 2. Unbounded decaying distribution

In this case you're looking for something like a Gaussian with spherical symmetry. The radial CDF of such a distribution scales with `R^(D-1)`. For the Gaussian, this is called the Rayleigh distribution in 2D,  Maxwell in 3D, and chi in the general case. These are available directly through the [`scipy.stats.rayleigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html), [`scipy.stats.maxwell`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html) and [`scipy.stats.chi`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi.html) objects, respectively.

In this case, radius has less meaning, but it can be interpreted as the standards deviation of your distribution.

The unbounded version of your function (also vectorized), then becomes:

```
def sample_sphere(s, d, n):
    radii = scipy.stats.chi.rvs(df=d, scale=s, size=(n, 1))
    directions = np.random.normal(size=(n, d))
    directions *= radii / np.linalg.norm(directions, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return directions
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for the thorough explanation!